# Alterar nome de uma variavel em um dataframe R

Tags: r

Tenho um dataframe com 34846 observações e 15 variaveis, gostaria de saber como tenho que fazer para alterar o nome de uma variavel.                       Exemplo:Tenho a variavel "Country" e gostaria de renomear para "Pais"

Answer (score 6):

Com `dplyr` você pode fazer assim:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% rename(Pais = Country)
```

Comment: Ou com uma sintaxe mais curta, já que está usando pipes: `df %<>% rename(Pais = Country)`

Answer (score 5):

Usando `grep` para achar o número da coluna que quer mudar de nome:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  'Year' = 2015:2018,
  'Country' = 'Brazil',
  'Continent' = 'America'
)

names(dados)[grep('Country', names(dados))] <- 'País'

> dados
  Year   País Continent
1 2015 Brazil   America
2 2016 Brazil   America
3 2017 Brazil   America
4 2018 Brazil   America
```

Answer (score 4):

Outra maneira, mas sem utilizar pacotes.

```
x = names(dataset)
x[(names(dataset) == "Country")] = "Pais"
colnames(dataset) = x
```

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode fazer isso:

```
colnames(dados)[1]<-'Pais' # 1 é o número da coluna Country
```